# How does 'items_new_path' differs from 'new_items_path'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing, requestdispatcher

I've noticed an unexpected behavior in the Rails Routing dispatcher, and I wonder if this violates the "Principle of Least Surprise".

When defining RESTful routes like in `resources :items, only: [:index, :new]` we get, as expected, these routings:

```
  Prefix Verb URI Pattern          Controller#Action
   items GET  /items(.:format)     items#index
new_item GET  /items/new(.:format) items#new
```

The same should be achieved defining each route by hand, using these two lines:

```
get '/items' => 'items#index'
get '/items/new' => 'items#new'
```

Now, the first line of the two is exactly the same, infact if you try to define both `resources :items, only: :index` and `get '/items' => 'items#index'` one Named Route get "masked" by the other:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern      Controller#Action
 items GET  /items(.:format) items#index
       GET  /items(.:format) items#index
```

but the second line gives another result: `items_new GET  /items/new(.:format) items#new`.

Try to define both ways, and you get two Named Route for the same URI:

```
   Prefix Verb URI Pattern          Controller#Action
 new_item GET  /items/new(.:format) items#new
items_new GET  /items/new(.:format) items#new
```

So why does the helper method change? Moreover when defining each route you don't even get a Named Route for the `edit` and `show` actions (try it by yourself).

Shouldn't the keyword `resources` be just a shortcut to avoid declaring separate routes for `index`, `show`, `new`, `edit`, `create`, `update` and `destroy` actions (as it's stated [in the doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing.html))?

Comment: It looks like it is starting at the right and working its way left underscoring `/`. If you want to specify the name just do `get 'items/new', as: 'new_items'` or whatever you want the named path to be

Comment: Sure, that will work. However the question is not about how to make it work, instead it's: "is it something wrong going on here?" Take the example of defining both `resources :items` and trying to declare `get '/items/new' => 'items#new', as: 'new_item'`: rake would prevent it, raising: _ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_item' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the :as option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming._ But `resources :items` and `get '/items' => 'items#index'` bypass the check.